# Recursion the optimal solution in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I'm getting a headache over this. I'm building a system, that can handle a number of projects, groups and file references.
Please take a look at this:
[image]

A user should be able to create an infinite number of projects, an infinite numbers of groups and attach an infinite number of file references - much like an ordinary PC file structure works with drive-letters, folders and files.

All of the mentioned elements resides inside a MySQL database. However, I'm not sure if this (see below) is the optimal way of structuring the whole thing:

[image]

As you can see, it contains one entity called "Xrefs", containing projects and groups. The rows points inside itself, probably making it ideal to do a recursive call when retrieving the data.

A different approach could be to create 1 entity for projects, 1 entity for groups and 1 entity for file references... as well as 1 helper entity, that ties the three entities together, also containing a "parent" value, that (similar to the first solution) refers to the upper level tuples in order to create a hierachy.

If you were to build a similar project, what would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit one of the best known restrictions of MySQL: the ability to use what is called recursive queries (PostgreSQL) or CTE queries (Oracle). There are some possibles workarounds, but considering a project with this kind of requirements you'd probably suffer a lot with many other well known MySQL limitations. Even SQLLite would be more usefull (except for the one concurrent user restriction) on this matter.

DBIx::Class has some components to help you circumvent this MySQL limitations, search for **Nested Trees**, **Ordered Trees**, **WITH RECURSIVE QUERY**… `[DBIx::Class::Tree::NestedSet][1]`

You will need support for something like: [7.8. WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html), which MySQL do not offer to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Much appreciated! As mentioned in relation to the other feedback, I'm trying out an Oracle solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is fine - since you are building a tree, not a general graph, there is no need for a separate table that ties entities together. I would put projects into their own table, because they appear to stand on their own, unless you must support hierarchy among projects as well.

However, given that your RDBMS is MySQL, you would have problems building recursive queries. For example, try thinking of a query that would give you all files related to `xfer_id` of `1` (i.e. the project). None of the files is tied to that ID, so you need to locate your first-level groups, then your second level groups, and then tie files to them. Since your groups can be nested in any number of levels, your query would have to be recursive as well.

Although you can certainly do it, [it is currently not simple, and requires writing stored procedures](http://guilhembichot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html). A common approach for situations like that is to build the tree in memory, with some assistance from RDBMS. The trick is to store the `id` of the top project in each group, i.e.

```
xfer_id xfer_fk xfer_top
------- ------- --------
    1      -       1
    2      1       1
    3      1       1
    4      3       1
    5      3       1
```

Now a query with the condition `WHERE xfer_top=...` will give your all the individual "parts", which could be combined in memory without having to bring the entire table in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. I was unaware of this limitation, so I've just installed an Oracle database to play with - hopefully, this will result in a viable solution.